# Is it possible to render the normal to the screen on THREE.JS?

Tags: javascript, three.js, glsl, webgl

I'm playing with Three.js's composer. I want to:

1. Render the normal informations of all meshes to a texture
2. Render the screen normally
3. Only then use those in the post-processing phase

How is it possible?